# Haskell - How to declare Positions function with using Find?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm very new to learning how to program in Haskell.

I have an example of the method `positions`:

```
positions :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
positions x xs = [i | (y, i) <- zip xs [0..], y == x]
```

My goal is to find a way to define the `positions` function, but with the `find` method.

The `find` method:

```
find :: Eq a => a -> [(a,b)] -> [b]
find k t = [v | (m, v) <- t, m == k]
```

Can someone explain how you declare a `positions` function with using **only** the `find` function?

I don't understand how you can keep track of the index with the `find` function.

Comment: Using `find` here would make matters very complicated, and furthermore probably inefficient. Since for each element the `find` yields, we would need to iterate over the (remainder) of the list. I do not really see why this would be helpful.

Comment: It's for practicing purposes, I just want to know how you can define such function.

Comment: With explicit recursion, and `takeWhile`, etc. But it will nullify the purpose of `find` anyway.

Comment: Notice the similarities between the list comprehension in `find` and the one in `positions`, and see how you could transform the one into the other.

Comment: The positions and find function you are given are really similar ... Just use zip as in (positions) before calling find.

Comment: I'm looking for a way without the `zip` function. So how can I define positions with only the `find` function?

Comment: no, you can't. you will use `find` to process the output of `zip ... [0..]`.

Comment: @476rick If I take your requirement at face value ("only the `find` function"), then *only the `find` function* can be implemented. Nothing else. You must use something else in addition to `find` -- a lambda, a variable, another data type, another function, *something* -- if you want to have anything that isn't exactly `find`. (...and, to connect all the dots, `positions` isn't `find`, so if you want to implement `positions`, you will need to use more than just `find`.)

Comment: both `find` and `positions` are functions, not methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start by re-writing `positions` as

```
positions x xs = map (\(_, i) -> i) . filter (\(y, _) -> y == x) $ zip xs [0..]
```

and we re-write `find` as

```
find k t       = map (\(_, v) -> v) . filter (\(m, _) -> m == k) $ t
-- or,
find x         = map (\(_, i) -> i) . filter (\(y, _) -> y == x)
```

and then simply notice that the two pieces of code are *exactly* the same (after the renaming of variables):

```
positions x xs = find x                                          $ zip xs [0..]
```

`find` only accepts lists of *pairs*, then filters them and extracts the second component; you will have to use *something* (like, *`zip`*) to produce the pairs for `find` to process. There's *no* way around it.

---

Of course `positions` can also be coded without the `zip` part (instead using e.g. `mapAccumL`) but then it doesn't need the `find`:

```
-- mapAccumL :: (acc -> x -> (acc, y)) -> acc -> [x] -> (acc, [y])

positions :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [Int]
positions x = concat . snd . mapAccumL g 0 
  where
  g acc y = (acc+1, [acc | y == x])
```

We could make it produce the list as expected by `find`, artificially, but it would be redoing a lot of work and would just be a re-implementation of the `zip` with enumeration part (so, not the `find` by itself), anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Look:

```
positions x xs = [i | (y, i) <- zip xs [0..], y == x]
find      k t  = [v | (m, v) <- t           , m == k]
```

They look pretty similar! We can make it even more striking by just renaming `k` to `x`, `m` to `y`, and `v` to `i` in the implementation of `find`:

```
positions x xs = [i | (y, i) <- zip xs [0..], y == x]
find      x t  = [i | (y, i) <- t           , y == x]
```

So now it's clear: all we have to do is have `positions` pass `zip xs [0..]` as the `t` argument to `find`.

```
positions x xs = find x (zip xs [0..])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although I don't want to use the zip function for this.